# Set of Critical point of a smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions

> Let $F:\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$, $n≤m$, $F\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathcal{U})$. Let $Crit(F):=\lbrace p\in\mathcal{U}\mid \ dF_{p} \ is \ not \ surjective.\rbrace$. Prove that $Crit(F)$ is closed.

I thought to define a function

$$h:\mathcal{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

$$h(p)=det(A_{p})$$

Where $A\in Mat_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is an arbitrary minor $n\times n$ of $dF_{p}$.

$h$ is continuous and $Crit(F)=h^{-1}(0)$ so is closed. Is it right?

Comment: The usual method of using sequences to show something is closed is to take a convergent sequence in your set and show that its limit is contained in the set. This shows that your set contains all of its limit points and is hence closed.

Comment: Surjectivity has something to do with the rank of $dF_p$, which has something to do with the vanishing or non-vanishing of minors, which depend continuously on $p$.

Comment: @Thorgott I though also about this but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: @Nicholas Roberts Ok, but in this case I should use the smoothness of the function to show that lim f(p_{n}) = f(p) ?

Comment: I am unsure about the question specifically. I was just outlining a general method to show that a set is closed in a metric space. But yes, if a function is continuous at the sequence's limit point, then $f(p_n) \rightarrow f(p)$.

Comment: I edited the question with an idea

Comment: If $n\leq m$, then it is slightly easier. If $n=m$, then we can take $h(p)=\operatorname{dF_p}$. On the other hand if $m\geq n$ we have $Crit(F)=\mathcal{U}$ (there is no surjective map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m>n$).

Comment: In the general case you would need to take several functions (for every $n\times n$ submatrix another function) and then take the intersection over all the preimages of $\{0\}$.

Comment: if t is the cardinality of the set of all n×n submatrix of dF. I define$ h:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{t}$

Comment: h(p) = (A_{1_{p}},\ldots A_{t_{p}}) so $crit(F)=h^{-1}(0)$ and we have the asserption. Is it right?